# Function to evaluate validity of numerical palindrome for floating point numbers using Python

Tags: python, floating-point, int

So there are plenty of algorithms to evaluate whether an int is a palindrome, i.e.

```
def ReverseNumber(n, partial=0):
    if n == 0:
        return partial
    return ReverseNumber(n // 10, partial * 10 + n % 10)
```

or this one:

```
def isPalindrome(x):
    if (x < 0):
        return False
    div = 1
    while (x / div >= 10):
        div *= 10
    while (x != 0):
        l = x / div
        r = x % 10
        if (l != r):
            return False
        x = (x % div) / 10
        div /= 100
    return True
```

However what I'd like to do is assess whether a number such as `1.01` or `22.22` and so on, whether such numbers are themselves palindromes.

How could either of those algorithms above be adapted to function for `floats` in addition to `ints`?

This is the code I'm using to call it:

```
import sys

# This method determines whether or not the number is a Palindrome
def isPalindrome(x):
    x = str(x).replace('.','')
    a, z = 0, len(x) - 1
    while a < z:
        if x[a] != x[z]:
            return False
        a += 1
        z -= 1
    return True

if '__main__' == __name__:

    trial = int(sys.argv[1])

    # check whether we have a Palindrome
    if isPalindrome(trial):
        print("It's a Palindrome!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is just convert the number to a string, then compare characters from the ends to the middle. The string conversion is less expensive than repeated multiplications and divisions.

```
def isPalindrome(x):
    x = str(x).replace('.','')
    a, z = 0, len(x) - 1
    while a < z:
        if x[a] != x[z]:
            return False
        a += 1
        z -= 1
    return True
```

Comment: You could also just do `return x == x[::-1]`.

Comment: I'm getting this error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.01'`

Comment: Where are you using `int()`?

Comment: @Blender what do you mean? Can you explain further please

Comment: @chepner ah yea- I'd wrapped the console input in an `int` before- but you're right- if I remove that- then it's all good- please forgive me for my `n00b` error :/

Comment: @s.matthew.english: `x == x[::-1]` checks to see if `x` is a palindrome.

Comment: `x[::-1]` creates a new string with the characters of `x` reversed, so the explicit loop in my answer gets spread across two implicit loops (one to do the reversal, another to do the character-by-character comparison of the two strings).